# use common template for all pages of website

Tags: php, html, architecture, templates

ok, the title did not make much sense but this is what i am planning to do. I have designed a template for my website, with head body and div for specific stuff and everything.  The website consists of header file, footer file, right-side column, header dropdown menu and a main body which would be present beneath the header dropdown menu, to the left of the right-side column, and above the footer. Right now there is some content is this main body area. What i am trying to achieve is that whenever any link is clicked on any of the other parts of the webpage, i want that content to be displayed in this main body. Right now i am copying this template to each and every page, but I want to keep this standard template as index.php and then replace main body content based on the link clicked. This is a php based website. Are there any examples where i can see how this can be achieved? or is there any standard procedure to do this. Please guide me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple way to do this:

### index.php

```
<?php

function putPage($page) {
    // put a list of allowed pages here
    $allowed = array('page1', 'page2');

    $page = trim($page);
    $page = (in_array($page, $allowed)) ? $page : 'home';

    echo @file_get_contents('.\html\\' . $page . '.html');

}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- put stylesheets, js files, etc. here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- you can have a nav bar or something here -->
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="?page=page1">Page 1</a> <a href="?page=page2">Page 2</a>
        </div>
        <?php  putPage($_GET['page']); ?>
        <!-- put a footer here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Then just put .html pages with the contents in an html subfolder.
The script will fetch them and insert them in the body.

Comment: Thank you... this made it very simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achieve this.  Off hand the two obvious ones I would say are:

1. Ajax to obtain content with event handlers attached to links/buttons/menus that produce maincontent specific to the request.
   This requires server and client side scripting to achieve. 
   [w3 ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
2. Or alternatively use mod_rewrite with apache to determine what content to load in index.php page.  For example with mod rewrite you may have a link http://www.site.com/subject/content/item# as a link structure.  This could translate to www.site.com/index.php?subject=&content=&id= And these GET values would allow you to determine what to display in main content area.
   This requires server side scripting and configuration of apache or (any web server with similar functionality to mod_rewrite). 
   [mod_rewrite - apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is called either a [Template View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/templateView.html) as far as you build your link specific HTML completely in PHP. You create a page layout template containing some wildcards. You load the template into a string and use string replacements or XML functions (more fancy but only suggestive if transformation is more complex).

Otherwise it is called [Two Step View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html) where you create the page layout template (as above) and a specific template for the links. Now first load the link specific template, put your dynamic content into (same techniques as above), load the page layout template and put the previous transformed specific template into.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<?php

        $pag = array(1 => 'Home.php', 3 => '2.php');
        echo require $pag[(int)@$_GET['p'] | 1];
?>
```